# How to return file path from wget command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, wget

Is it possible to get the file path with wget from bash?

I tried this, but it echo the file not the file path:

```
file=$(wget -qO- https://ninite.com/java/ninite.exe)
echo "$file"
```

EDIT:
I want something like this https://github.com/phoemur/wgetter#api-usage but in bash with wget.

Comment: What do you mean by file path?  You are asking `wget` to output to `STDOUT`.

Comment: The full path of the downloaded file: for example /home/user1/Desktop/the-file-name.ext

Comment: means what is the path of file on server from  root ? or from the webserver root ?

Comment: The path of the downloaded file (where the file is saved on my machine).

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the file name from wget's output only:

```
file=$(LANG=C wget URL 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*- \`\(.*\)' saved.*/\1/p")
echo "$file:"
cat "$file"
```

Try it with google for example:

```
file=$(LANG=C wget google.de 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*- \`\(.*\)' saved.*/\1/p")
echo "$file:"
cat "$file"
```

Output:

```
index.html:
... content
```

Comment: I use this url as example, sometime you don't get the filename like that. Moreover, I want to retrieve the filename from a wget command.

Answer (score 1):

A hack which will get you the file name by ensuring it's the only file in the current directory:

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
wget http://example.org
for file in *
do
    path="$file"
done
```

This should work no matter the encoding or whatever munging `wget` does to the file name (for example, if a URL containing `%0A` gets saved with a newline).

Answer (score 0):

How about just specifying where to store the files?

```
# wget -P /root/test example.com
--2014-05-12 09:52:58--  http://example.com/
Resolving example.com (example.com)... 93.184.216.119, 2606:2800:220:6d:26bf:1447:1097:aa7
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|93.184.216.119|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1270 (1.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `/root/test/index.html'

100%[===========================================================================================================>] 1,270       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2014-05-12 09:52:58 (95.5 MB/s) - `/root/test/index.html' saved [1270/1270]
```